# Downloading data from Oracle on .net 6

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that download data from oracle but it is in .net 4.3 and it works just fine, right now I've been asked to migrate every project we have to .net 6 and now it isnt working its the exact same code and it fails to connect. Only difference is that previous dll was taken from my oracle client install which is x86 and new one was downloaded from nuget and its x64 I think it has something to do with the installation of oracle client in my pc but i cannot install another version because its at my work and y dont have the previlieges to do it nor they would help me to do it, heres the code which is the exact same one I'm using with the x86 dataaccess dll:

thanks a lot.

```
   Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client 
        Dim OraCon As OracleConnection = New
            OracleConnection
             Dim OraBldr As New OracleConnectionStringBuilder
 OraBldr.UserID = "*****"
                    OraBldr.Password = "*****"
                    OraBldr.ConnectionTimeout = 86400
                   OraBldr.DataSource = "(DESCRIPTION=" _
                           + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oseb)(PORT=1562)))" _
                          + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service)));"
                    OraBldr.Pooling = False
         OraCon.Open()
```

Comment: "it fails to connect" - how do you know that? (Also, it is intended that connection pooling is used, and that connections are created only for the duration of a query then disposed of, not for the lifetime of the application.)

Comment: I know it fails to connect because it throws error "ORA-12514 listener doesnt recognize service" but its the same tns I use in .net 4.3 and same connection string

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by downloading Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 3.21.110 from nuget